# Show UIToolBar in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uitoolbar

I have an `UiToolbar`, and I want to show it when tapped.
I have used UITextBox, and when I tap inside this textbox, this `UiToolbar` is shows.

My Swift code is:

```
txf_provider.inputView = pickerProvider
txf_provider.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
```

Now, I want to tap to `UILabel`. It shows, but property of Label has only `get` method.

Comment: Try this "Tap recognizer for UILABEL"
["Tap recognizer for UILABEL"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154340/how-to-get-uilabel-to-respond-to-tap)

Comment: Follow this to update the label http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542745/how-to-update-a-uilabel-in-xcode-programmatically-without-xib-files

Comment: thanks for your comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me. Let me know if this is what you were looking for:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var toolBar = UIToolbar(frame:CGRectMake(0, 524, 320, 44))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black
       self.view.addSubview(toolBar)


    }
}
```